Form of the Hamiltonian at Half-filling
I am trying to understand why chemical potential $= U/2$ is considered to be at half-filling in the case of the Hubbard Model Hamiltonian. So when I substitute this in its Hamiltonian, this is the equation I am getting   $$ H = K.E-\frac{U}{2}\Sigma [n_{j,up}n_{j,down} + (n_{j,up} - n_{j,down})^{2}]. $$
I am trying to understand how this works graphically and mathematically to see how this incorporates the half-filling condition. I plotted only the second term and setting $n_{j,up}$ to a constant either zero or one. Also, just want to confirm that $n_{j,up}$ can only take 0, 1 - and no intermediate values.
So when I plotted this, I am getting a parabola, at $n_{j,up} = 0$, its the normal parabola open upward with vertex at the origin and for $n_{j,up} = 1$, its shifted by some amount. When I consider half-filling for one-site hubbard model, it can have only four eigenbasis - $ |0\rangle, |up\rangle, |down\rangle, |up, down\rangle$, so the possible states at half-filling are $|up\rangle, |down\rangle$, so since only one of them only possible in this type of filling, then I am getting $\frac{-U}{2}$ added to the energy. Is it because we are adding this energy with the half-factor in it, we are calling this as the half-filling type. I do not understand completely how to interpret the half-filling case from this plot or the expression itself intuitively. I want to understand this in general, as through the form of the Hamiltonian itself. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

It is cleaner to formalise the problem using second quantisation. For the fermion Hubbard model with Hamiltonian:
$$
H = -t\sum c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma}+U\sum n_{i\uparrow}n_{i\downarrow}+\mu\sum n_{i\sigma} \\
n_{i\sigma} = c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{i\sigma}
$$
you have a particle-hole symmetry obtained by the following substitution:
$$
c_{i\sigma}\to (-1)^ic_{i\sigma}^\dagger
$$
This gives the following change in number operators:
$$
n_{i\sigma}\to1-n_{i\sigma}
$$
So the Hamiltonian is transformed as (ignoring the additive constant):
$$
H = -t\sum c_{i\sigma}^\dagger c_{j\sigma}+U\sum n_{i\uparrow}n_{i\downarrow}+(U-\mu)\sum n_{i\sigma}
$$
At half filling, the particle hole symmetry leaves the system unchanged. Since the new Hamiltonian is equal to the original one, this imposes:
$$
\mu = U-\mu
$$
i.e. $\mu = U/2$.
Hope this helps.

Perfect +1. (and then I have to add some irrelevant characters).

@LPZ in bose-hubbard model, the U term has 1/2 coefficient to it, I read that it is because of hermiticity irrespective of the filling. I do not understand how it can be due to hermiticity as the mu term does not have the 1/2 coefficient. Any opinions on this?

Do you have any specific references?

Just to spell out the last steps of @LPZ perfect answer: when $\mu=U/2$ the Hamiltonian (and so its ground state if it's non-degenerate) is invariant under the unitary particle-hole symmetry transformation.
As such the expectation value
$
\langle n_{i\sigma} \rangle
$
must be equal to the expectation value after the transformation. That is
$$
\langle n_{i\sigma} \rangle = 1-\langle n_{i\sigma}\rangle
$$
which means $\langle n_{i\sigma} \rangle =1/2$, that is half filling.
